# What is the difference between these two SSDs?

Tags: ssd

I'm finally ready to take the plunge and go SSD. From what I've read, Intel X25-M is the best on the market. However, I'm completely confused as to what the difference is between these two items on Amazon (UK):

- [First](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Intel-SSD-160GB-2-5-Inch/dp/B001TKA4JM/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1255542811&sr=8-3)
- [Second](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Intel-X25-M-Mainstream-Solid-State/dp/B002N5F5LE/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1255542811&sr=8-4)

Obviously they look different and the price discrepancy is a massive £150, but I can't see anything else different. Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks,
Kent

Comment: Seriously, what I wouldn't give to have £369.71 floating around right now :(

Comment: There are slightly cheaper options available, such Scan: http://www.scan.co.uk/Products/160GB-Intel-MLC-Flash-25-SSD-SATA-3Gb-s-Read-250MB-s-Write-70MB-s-OEM

Comment: Also, confusingly, the images on the product pages should be swapped...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2nd link is to the generation 2 drives. The G2s are faster and cheaper, go with that one. You can tell by the end of the model number where it says G101 and G2R5. The G1 is generation 1, the G2 is Generation 2.

Comment: Wow - that's good news! Faster and cheaper. They couldn't make it any less obvious what the difference is, perhaps so people still buy the G1s thinking they're better.